# Sorting float number and awk

Tags: awk, sort, numeric-data

Consider the following `foo.dat` file with 11 columns:

```
  893    1  754  946  193   96   96     293.164     293.164     109.115     70.8852
  894    1  755  946  192   95   96     291.892     292.219     108.994      70.821
  895    1  755  947  193   95   97     290.947     291.606     109.058     70.5709
  896    1  755  947  193   95   97     290.002     290.663     109.122     70.5053
  897    1  755  948  194   95   98     289.057     290.057     109.187     70.2532
  898    1  754  949  196   96   99     288.444     289.456      109.44          70
  899    1  754  950  197   96  100     287.501     288.862     109.506     69.7458
  900    1  754  949  196   96   99     286.559     287.578     109.573     69.8637
```

I'd like to filter the columns 11 and 9 and print only these on a file, but in **ascending order on 1st new column**, that is, after printing 11 and 9 columns, sort the output by numerical rule.

I tried

```
awk  -F' ' '{printf "%-12s%-12s\n", $11, $9}' foo.dat | sort -g
```

but the output is strange around `70`. It is

```
70.2532 290.057
70 289.456
70.5053 290.663
```

Why `70` is not before `70.2532`? Looks like `.` is being ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you have a locale using a comma as decimal separator. This should fix that issue:

```
awk  -F' ' '{printf "%-12s%-12s\n", $11, $9}' foo.dat | LC_ALL=C sort -g
```

Comment: You are completely right about the locale. I never had imaged this could be the solution. It works like a charm. Thanks so much.